# Interface advice for creating a simple Windows program

Tags: json, windows, user-interface

I am developing a project to be used by a company. Basically the project is an android app (already developed), to be used in tablets, that reads a json file and generates a survey (to be done face-to-face with some intricacies). The JSON file can be seen [here](https://github.com/Asura14/asura14.github.com/raw/master/img/newSurvey.json).

That was the agreed part but they also want me to create a windows program that allows their (non-tech) workers to use in order to create the survey which is then saved as a JSON file to be used by the APP.

Finally, my question is: **Any advice on what is the best way to develop this simple program?**
Basically: write survey title, questions, answers and save in a JSON file.

I started developing with .Net but honestly it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out .Net was the solution. Since this question got no replies

I decided to try a bunch of solutions and because both C# is easy to use and [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is a pretty good solution to saving class objects to a json type file I stook with it.